# Why can't I access state in ComponentDidMount?

Tags: react-native

I have this code for React Native:

```
componentWillMount() {
    shiftKeys = []; // need to clear previously set data or we will get dupicate array key errors
    // get the current user from firebase
    const userData = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;
    const profileRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('userdata').child(userData.uid);
    profileRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('licenseType') && snapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('licenseState') && snapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('distance')) {
        this.setState({
          licenseType: snapshot.val().licenseType,
          licenseState: snapshot.val().licenseState,
          distancePref: snapshot.val().distance,
        });
      console.log('State1', this.state.distancePref)
      } else {
        // redirect back to profile screens because we need three values above to search.
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Onboarding1')
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('State2', this.state.distancePref)
    var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
      center: [45.616422, -122.580453],
      radius: 1000// need to set dynamically
      });
```

I think this is some kind of scope issue?

When I look at the console log, State 1 is set correctly, but State 2 prints nothing.

In my app I need to look up a users distance preference, then use that to run a query.

How do I pass the value from componentWillMount to componentDidMount?

Comment: For clarification, I'm wanting to replace the value of 

`radius: 1000` 

with 

`radius: this.state.distancePref`

Answer (score 1):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

setState in componentWillMount - bad way. You do not solve the problem this way, because state will not be updated until componentDidMount (see lifecycle). Check your condition when creating the state, in the constructor.
Or you can solve the problem using redux.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried moving the code into componentDidMount and it still doesn't work.  I think that you are correct that I need to do this with redux.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue with this problem had to do with my not understanding how react and react native render the code.

I was trying to get users info from firebase, then set preferences, then use those preferences to run a search.

I added redux and thunk to handle the getting and saving of the users preferences separately from (and before) the user has a chance to search.